# RegularExpressionAttribute not working with the expression to test dot(\.)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

All I need to validate is a decimal point (or a dot).

I used the following regular expression:

```cs
"\.+"
```

I tested both with the .NET compiler and JS testers and the expression appears to be valid.

I have the following attribute in the Model:

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"\.+", ErrorMessage = @"Decimals are not permitted. 
   Please enter a Value that is a whole number.")]
```

It renders the following HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The value must be a number" 
data-val-range="Please enter a value that is a positive number." 
data-val-range-max="200" data-val-range-min="0" 
data-val-regex="Decimals are not permitted. Please enter a Value that 
is a whole number." data-val-regex-pattern="\.+" 
id="OtnLngLpgIenAmount" name="OtnLngLpgIenAmount" type="text" value="5" 
class="input-validation-error">
```

The output is

> **Value :** 5
>  *Decimals are not permitted. Please enter a Value that is a whole number.*

Not sure what's happening here. I would appriciate any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular Expressions are *required* formats. You're saying *I require only decimal points*. You want to invert it. Perhaps this (not a regex expert.. ):

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^.]+")]
```

This says *anything but a decimal point*.

If you supply more details about the format I can help you create a more specific regular expression.

Comment: The backslash can be removed within character classes.

Comment: You are spot on Simon, thanks for pointing this out. Also thanks to @acheong87 for making the expression look neat.